# How do I parent an object to a bone in the blender hierarchy?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, rigging, importing

So, I'm trying to make a simple RPG game using Blender and Unity. I would like to have an empty object to be used as a weapon holding position parented to my right hand bone so that I can switch weapons in and out and they'll be able to animate along with my character by being the child of the empty position. The problem I am having is that I can't get the empty position to be a child of the specific right hand bone, only the armature. Is there a way to make this work? Also, if this isn't a good procedure to accomplish what I am trying to do, please enlighten me with the proper way, I'm kind of a noob, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing similar things recently and got it working. What you are talking about sounds strange to me because the "empty object" you mention sounds more like Unity's empty game object instead of Blender's empty, but anyway, if you want to parent anything to a bone in Blender, select only that bone in pose mode, go select the object, then shift select the bone, press ctrl+p you should see a menu which allows you to parent the object to just the bone. In the case of Unity, you just parent the object's transform to the bone's transform. If your armature is humanoid, you can find the right-hand bone with Animator.GetBoneTransform method.

Comment: Yep! Readers, pay extra attention to the words "in Pose Mode". Because an Empty would be a separate object outside of the armature, so this is the way it must be done. Also, since Blender is undergoing a big transition now from 2.79b to 2.8, it would be good for OP to mention which version we are discussing. (In my 2.8 Beta I get an unexpected offset issue when parenting an external object to a bone, but then my beta is a couple months old, things may have changed since then.)